# Retrieving json objects from php and display to textfield

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I created a search page with jquery that will display result on same page and I succeed of doing it but the jquery that I made can only show data with index 0 and it will fail if I searched other data with differenct index. I am having Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StudentNumber' of undefined error in console log.How can I search json object with data matching what is type in the search bar then populate the textbox from db. Please help.... thanks....

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function(){
var txtValue = $("#txtsearch").val();
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"<?php echo site_url('enrollment/studSearch');?>",
data: {q:txtValue},
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
  //console.log(data.studinfo[0].StudentNumber);
  $("#studentnum").val(data.studinfo[0].StudentNumber);
  $("#yearLevel").val(data.studinfo[0].YearLevel);
  $("#lastname").val(data.studinfo[0].LastName);
  $("#firstname").val(data.studinfo[0].FirstName);
  $("#middlename").val(data.studinfo[0].MiddleName);
  $("#txtTuition").val(data.studinfo[0].TuitionFee);
  $("#txtMisc").val(data.studinfo[0].MiscFee);
  $("#txtAddFee").val(data.studinfo[0].AdditionalFee);
  $("#txtTotal").val(data.studinfo[0].Total);
  $("#modeofpayment").val(data.studinfo[0].ModeOfPayment);
  $("#payAmount").val(data.studinfo[0].PayableAmount);
},
});
});
```

my controller:

```
public function studSearch()
{
    $str = $this->input->post('q');
    $data['studinfo'] = $this->emodel->search_Student($str);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and the model:

```
 function search_Student($str)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('studentinfo a');
    $this->db->join('studFinance b','a.StudentNumber = b.StudentNumber');
    $this->db->like('a.StudentNumber',$str);
    $this->db->or_like('a.LastName',$str);
    $this->db->or_like('a.FirstName',$str);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
    }
```

this is the view:

```
  <div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="page-inner">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
  <h2>Billing Page</h2>
 </div>
  </div>

  <hr />
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
 <?php
    $attributes = array("class"=>"form-  horizontal","id"=>"billform","name"=>"billform",
  "autocomplete"=>"off");
    echo form_open("enrollment/ebilling",$attributes);
     ?>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
  Personal Information
 </div>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
 <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Search:</label>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  <input type="text" id="txtsearch" name="txtsearch" class="form-control"/>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
  <hr />
   <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Student Number:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
  <input type="text" readonly id="studentnum" name="studentnum" value="<?php echo set_value('studentnum');?>" class="form-control"/>
 </div>
  </div>     
 <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
 <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Year Level:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
   <input type="text" readonly id="yearLevel" name="yearLevel" value="<?php echo set_value('yearLevel');?>" class="form-control"/>
   </div>

 <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Last Name:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="<?php echo set_value('lastname');?>" readonly class="form-control" />
  </div>
   </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">   
<label class="control-label col-xs-2">First Name:</label>
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo set_value('firstname');?>" readonly class="form-control" />
  </div>
<label class="control-label col-xs-2">Middle Name:</label>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
 <input type=-"text" id="middlename" name="middlename" value="<?php echo set_value('middlename');?>" readonly class="form-control" />
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>

 <!-- END OF FIRST PANEL -->
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  Billing Mode
 </div>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="panel panel-info">
 <div class="panel-heading">
Student Account
 </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Tuition Fee:</label>
     <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" id="txtTuition" readonly name="txtTuition" value="      <?php echo set_value('txtTuition');?>" class="form-control"/>
       </div>
        </div>
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Miscellaneous Fee:</label>
     <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" id="txtMisc" readonly name="txtMisc" value="<?php echo set_value('txtMisc');?>" class="form-control"/>
       </div>
        </div>
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Additional Fee:</label>
     <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" id="txtAddFee" readonly name="txtAddFee" value="<?php echo set_value('txtAddFee');?>" class="form-control"/>
       </div>
        </div>
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Total:</label>
     <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" id="txtTotal" readonly name="txtTotal" value="<?php echo set_value('txtTotal');?>" class="form-control"/>
       </div>
        </div>
         </div>
          </div>
  <!-- END OF FIRST INSIDE PANEL -->
  <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  Payment
  </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
  <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Mode of Payment:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
  <input type="text" id="modeofpayment" name="modeofpayment" value="<?php echo set_value('modeofpayment');?>" readonly class="form-control"/>
     </div>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
  <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Payable Amount:</label>
   <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" id="payAmount" name="payAmount" value="<?php echo set_value('payAmount');?>" readonly class="form-control"/>
   </div>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
 <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Date:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
  <input type="date" id="pDate" name="pDate" value="<?php echo set_value('pDate');?>" class="form-control"/>
  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('pDate');?></span>
   </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
  <label class="control-label col-xs-5">OR Number:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
  <input type="text" id="orNum" name="orNum" value="<?php echo set_value('orNum');?>" class="form-control"/>
   <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('orNum');?></span>
   <input type="hidden" id="balance" name="balance"/>
   </div>
    </div>
   <!-- END OF SECOND INSIDE PANEL -->
     </div>
      </div>
       </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">           
  <table id="billTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>OR Number</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
  <th>Date</th>
   </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>

     </tbody>
      <tfoot>
       <td>Balance</td>

         </tfoot>
      </table>
       </div>
 <!-- END OF TABLE -->
 <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddPayment" name="btnAddPayment"
   value="Add Payment"/>
   <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnReset" name="reset">Reset</button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); 
    echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>
    </div>
    </div>
     </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Show what `console.log(data);` displays. Maybe it's just an empty array.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LastName' of undefined I changed it from StudentNumber to LastName...... I searched a name that have an index 1.....

Comment: No, change it to exactly `console.log(data);` to see full `data` var.

Comment: Object {studinfo: Array[0]}...

Comment: See, it's empty, there's nothing to show. You have to somehow react on empty result and not try to fill any fields.

Comment: I added .studinfo in data and when I type an item that is in index 0 the console log displays object but when i type item that is not index 0 it display only []...

Comment: if I search doe the console log displays Object {StudentNumber: "201601001", StudentType: "newstudent", LastName: "doe", FirstName: "john", MiddleName: "doe"…} but when I search dawin the console log displays undefiend....

Comment: Sorry it's my fault I forgot that my mysql table are joined and if the other table not yet have data or empty it will really return empty... Thanks for the help by the way....